# Mongoid and ActiveRecord relations: undefined method `quoted_table_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mongodb, mongoid

```
class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :claim_template
end

class ClaimTemplate
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :contest
end

# console
Contest.new.claim_template
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `quoted_table_name' for ClaimTemplate:Class
```

ok, let's add `quoted_table_name` to `ClaimTemplate`:

```
def self.quoted_table_name
  "claim_templates"
end

# console
Contest.new.claim_template
#=> nil
# Cool!
# But:
Contest.last.claim_template
#=> TypeError: can't convert Symbol into String
```

So how can I configure my models to work properly with each other

*PS:*

Now I have this construction, which works fine, but I want to have benefits of Relations (`Assosiations`).

```
class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has_one :claim_temlate
  def claim_template
    ClaimTemplate.where(:contest_id => self.id).first
  end

  # Mongoid going to be crazy without this hack
  def self.using_object_ids?
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: What "benefits of Relations" are you hoping for? ActiveRecord associations operate under the assumption that both models in the association are ActiveRecord objects, so it's highly unlikely you'll able to get `has_one` and `belongs_to` workings out of the box together.

Comment: @Michael Fairley, I want to use all `Associations` methods to create new CleimTemplate through Contest, to make nested forms and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and so on. I don't see any problems to use both of them together as far as `Mongoid` and `ActiveRecord` are just abstractions and they can easily handle this behavior

Comment: @fl00r sure Mongoid and ActiveRecord are just abstractions and are both built on top of ActiveModel, but unless they both expose the exact same API and store the relations metadata in a compatible way, (which AFAIK is not the case) I don't think you will be able to get this kind of cross-odm relations working (of course without a lot of rewrite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this has been formally implemented yet.  Associations are handled mostly through `ActiveRecord::Reflection`, which is hardcoded to the idea of relational tables, see this class:

- [https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L190)

What that's suggesting is that there is no way ActiveRecord associations can work with things like Mongoid.

I recommend either building a gem to solve that problem by building a similar reflection wrapper for Mongoid, or just construct the associated objects manually.

Answer (score 3):

There is an interesting gem available called Tenacity which seems to do what you want, using t_has_one, t_has_many and t_belongs_to rather than the normal associations.

Because it currently only has those relations it is a bit limited, and I'm currently struggling with a many-to-many, but that may help you out.

Check it out here - https://github.com/jwood/tenacity

Comment: dude tenacity is no longer maintained can you suggest some other gem for this?

Comment: I haven't touched Mongo since shortly after I posted this (I moved to a different project) so I have no idea what the current landscape is, sorry.